# Uhlmann's Theorem: proof of $\text{tr}(A^{\dagger} B) = \langle m | A \otimes B |m\rangle $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-information, hilbert-space, density-operator

In p228, Chapter 9 of Mark Wilde's text , in the course of proving Uhlmann's theorem for quantum fidelity, it claims
$$\sum_{i,j} \langle i|^R \langle i|^A (U^R \otimes (\sqrt{\rho}\sqrt{\sigma})^A) |j\rangle^R |j\rangle^A  $$
$$=\sum_{i,j} \langle i|^R \langle i|^A (I^R \otimes (\sqrt{\rho}\sqrt{\sigma}U^T)^A) |j\rangle^R |j\rangle^A $$
which are equations (9.97) and (9.98) in the aforementioned text.

Meanwhile, in Nielsen & Chuang's text, exercise 9.16 requires to prove that
$$\text{tr}(A^{\dagger} B) = \langle m | A \otimes B |m\rangle $$
for $|m\rangle = \sum_{i} |i\rangle|i\rangle $ where $\{ |i\rangle \}$ is an orthonormal basis on some Hilbert space and A and B are operators on that space.

Each thing above is crucial in proof of Uhlmann theorem in respective textbook but I have no idea why they hold. $\text{tr}(A^{\dagger} B) = \sum_{i,j} {a_{ij}}^{*}b_{ij}$ whereas   $ \langle m | A \otimes B |m\rangle = \sum_{i,j} {a_{ij}} b_{ij } $ so why they equal? Could anybody give me any hint?

Answer (score 3):

The first equation can be proven by using that the maximally entangled state $\vert\Phi\rangle = \sum_i \vert i\rangle \vert i\rangle$ is invariant under $U\otimes \bar U$ for $U$ unitary,
$$
U\otimes \bar U \vert\Phi\rangle = \vert\Phi\rangle\ .
$$

In the second equation, a complex conjugate is missing, see http://www.michaelnielsen.org/qcqi/errata/errata/errata.html.